# Функция возвращает null

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема, функция возвращает null. Вроде бы, по синтаксису всё нормально, просмотрел справку PHP — всё соответствует, не пойму почему так.

Часть кода с функцией:

```
function SearchWord($query) {
    $find = "club";
    $search = strpos($query, $find);
    return $search;
}

SearchWord($getData['response']['items'][$i]['text']);
if($search == true) {
    echo "Get Word<br>";
}
```

Если нужно — вышлю весь код. Возможно, эту переменную нельзя вернуть?

P.S. Проверял само входящее значение в функцию — всё хорошо. Проверял возвращает ли `strpos()` true/false внутри самой функции — да, возвращает.

Comment: Вы возвращаемое значение не присваиваете никакой переменной.... `$search` внутри функции и умирает сразу после завершения, а `$search` вне функции - совсем другая и эти две переменных в разных контекстах... .либо пишите `$search = SearchWord($getData['response']['items'][$i]['text']);`  либо делайте `$search` глобальной (что не приветствуется)...... либо вообще `if (SearchWord($getData['response']['items'][$i]['text']))...` что правда трудночитаемо....в общем разные это переменные..почитайте про область видимости переменных.Нельзя где угодно объявить переменную и где угодно пользоваться её же

Comment: Что такое переменная `$search` в коде после вызова `SearchWord()`, откуда она взялась, какое отношение имеет к функции `SearchWord()`? (упс, опередили)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, точно, спасибо. О global я читал, как-то активно его использовал, в итоге код очень долго обрабатывался :(
Что-то сразу не догадался в if запихнуть, а про исчезновения переменной и из-за этого её вернуть нельзя -- вот этого не знал, спасибо! Странно, что об этом в справке информацию не нашёл. 

Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться результатом функции `SearchWord()` его придется явно записать в переменную `$search`, так как `$search` внутри функции `SearchWord()` и вне ее - это разные переменные.

```
function SearchWord($query){
    $find = "club";
    $search = strpos($query, $find);
    return $search;
}

$search = SearchWord($getData['response']['items'][$i]['text']);
if($search == true){
    echo "Get Word<br>";
}
```

В вашем варианте скрипт будет работать, если внутри функции `SearchWord()` объявить переменную `$search` глобальной

```
function SearchWord($query){
    global $search;
    $find = "club";
    $search = strpos($query, $find);
    return $search;
}
```

Однако, лучше избегать такой практики - это плохой тон, приводящий к множеству проблем, особенно, если приложение разрастается и становится большим.